# Let f : R →Z be the function

Tags: functions

[image]

The first one, consider a counterexample: suppose x= 3.2 or 3.3, but the f(x) value is the same one, thus it is not a one-one function? 
The second one, because there are several x value → same  f(x) value, thus it is a onto function...I am confused such prove is false or right..
And I do not know how solve the third question. Thank you!

Comment: See [Surjective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function): "a function f from a set X to a set Y is surjective (or onto), if for every element y in the codomain Y of f there is at least one element x in the domain X of f such that f(x) = y."

Answer (score 3):

(a) you are right. $f(3.2)=f(3.3)=6$ shows $f$ is not on-one(as does $f(0)=f(\frac13)=0$ and many other abundant counter-examples).

(b) Given $n\in\Bbb Z$, can you exhibit $x\in\Bbb R$ with $\lfloor 2x\rfloor =n$? If confused, ignore the floor initially.

(c) Note $f(x)$ is an  integer; can you simplify the expression for $f(x)$ for the case that $x$ is an integer?

Comment: So the third question:f(f(x))=2 2x(i do not know how to type floor)

Comment: So that is double floor 2x=2 2x(floor)?